# php confusion: increment value used as a reference

Tags: php, increment, byref

Consider the following code:

```
$a=0;
$b=&$a;
$a += ++$a + ++$a;
```

if I remove the `$b=&$a;`, I get `5`, if I don't, I get `6`. Can someone explain what is going on here? Thanks!